# Why are icons missing for certain programs in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons

For some of my programs, the icons have vanished. This applies to both the pinned Start Menu items and the programs in their program folders as well.

[image]

Inkscape and IrfanView have both had their icons disappear. SVG and image files associated with the respective programs still show the right icons -- it's just the main .exes that don't have icons any more.

How do I restore them?

Comment: Do you have any antivirus program running? Has it detected anything suspicious recently?

Comment: Yes, in fact -- Microsoft Security Essentials detected a very old virus on a very old IDE drive I plugged in a few days ago to retrieve a very old file.

Comment: Well, I guess that may be the cause of the problem. Try uninstaling and reinstalling Inkscape and IrfanView and see if it helps. **Don't run them** before this operation, also be sure to manually uninstall first and ensure no application files are left before reinstalling.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try the following.

Open Notepad and paste the below code.

```
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
cd /d %UserProfile%\AppData\Local
attrib –h IconCache.db
del IconCache.db
start explorer
```

save the file as a **.bat** file on your desktop.

Lastly, double click on the **.bat** file that you saved on your desktop and all icons should be restored.

<sub>[**Source**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/wrong-or-missing-program-icons-in-windows-7-start/3fb5be69-105a-40ca-a0ca-695b8bad41f8)</sub>

Comment: worked for me too, thank you @QMechanic73

Comment: If you are missing icons for windows explorer and notepad you may also need to delete the windows explorer icon and thumbnail cache databases in %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer however those files aren't immediately available for deletion after the taskkill command completes so it failed for me in a batch file.  Maybe a short wait would help after the taskkill as well.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it seems like a 3rd party program removed the root directories of these programs. Or it could have been you deleting something on accident. But that is the icon you get when a program root gets deleted but the shortcuts correlated with it don't get removed also

You're going to have to reinstall the programs that were deleted

Answer (score 0):

Its due to corrupted IconCache, You can delete the database file described above and reboot

Another workaround is temporarily setting your windows DPI Scale to medium (120 ppi)/or any other than default in advanced display settings

"Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display"

Log off and revert to your old DPI scaling